# Android studio native code navigation is not working

Tags: android-studio, android-native-library

When I click on usage of any function it shows me a dialog like below:
[image: ErrorImage]

This makes my code navigation in native very slow. I'm using Android Studio Arctic Fox.
I have NDK(SideBySide) and CMAKE installed. I'm able to build and debug native code.
I feel it's some settings / configuration issue. In my native code I don't find usage of functions or variables like we do in Java. Any help/clue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured the answer. It was an indexing issue of Android Studio(AS).
So, I closed AS. Used VisualStudio for indexing my code. And later opened AS. And AS now able to find reference of native C code. Damn you AS..